# Get first value outside where window with lag function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag

When using the lag function on time series in SQL Server, I always struggle with the *first* value in a time series.
Assume this trivial example

```
CREATE TABLE demo
    ([id] int, [time] date, [content] int)
;
INSERT INTO demo (id, time, content) VALUES
  (1, '2021-05-31', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
  (2, '2021-06-01', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
  (3, '2021-06-02',cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
  (4, '2021-06-03', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
(5, '2021-06-04', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
(6, '2021-06-05', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
(7, '2021-06-06', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
(8, '2021-06-07', cast(rand()*1000 as int)),
(9, '2021-06-08', cast(rand()*1000 as int));
```

I want to get all values and their previous value in June, so something like this

```
select content, lag(content, 1, null) over (order by time)
from demo
where time >= '2021-06-01'
```

so far so good, however, the first entry will result in null for the previous value.

Of course there are many solutions on how to fill the null value, e.g. subselecting a larger range etc. but for very large tables I somehow think there should be an elegant solution to this.

Sometimes I do stuff like this

```
select content, lag(content, 1, 
(select content from demo d1 join 
(select max(time) maxtime from demo where time < '2021-06-01') d2 on d1.time = d2.maxtime
)) over (order by time)
from demo
where time >= '2021-06-01'
```

Is there something more efficient? (note: of course for this trivial example I doesn't make a difference, but for tables with partition and 500'000'000 entries, one should find the most efficient solution)

Check out the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d6220/1)

Comment: Well what value do you want to display for the first value?

Comment: The first row has date 2021-06-01, the previous value is the one with date 2021-5-31 and content 1, so 1

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select content, lag(content) over (order by time)
      from demo d
     ) d
where time >= '2021-06-01';
```

This is probably going to scan the entire table.  However, you can create an index `demo(time, content)` to help the `lag()`.

Next, you can optimize this if you have a reasonable lookback period.  For instance, if there are records every month, just go back one month in the subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select content, lag(content) over (order by time)
      from demo d
      where time >= '2021-05-01'
     ) d
where time >= '2021-06-01';
```

This can also be very important if your data is partitioned -- as large tables are wont to be.

Comment: So, this is basically what I do all the time... doesn't seem to be something more efficient

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, going by your comments, you may first compute the lag over the entire unfiltered table, then subquery that based on date:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT time, content, LAG(content) OVER (ORDER BY time) lag_content
    FROM demo
)

SELECT content, lag_content
FROM cte
WHERE time >= '2021-06-01';
```

Comment: I tried this on my *big* table with half a billion entries and it went ridiculously fast. How is that possible? I would have thought the cte copies all data into the ram or so?

Comment: @rst I'm surprised it went that fast with such a large table, but in SQL Server, a CTE just gets inlined.  So, my answer is just doing `SELECT content, lag_content FROM ( ... cte here ...) t WHERE time >= '2021-06-01'`

Comment: sorry, that was an error on my side. The execution lasted several minutes. Using subqueries etc. is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like the null values to be? I've put them as 0  in the below example.

```
SELECT
    content,
    coalesce(LAG(content, 1, NULL) OVER(
        ORDER BY
            time
    ), content-1) lag_content
FROM
    demo
WHERE
    time >= '2021-06-01'
```

Output:

```
content lag_content
-------------------
      2           1
      3           2
      4           3
      5           4
      6           5
      7           6
      8           7
      9           8
```

Try it out here: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=656f0eeed32c5c857f6a8ab819e4315e)

Comment: The null value should actually be 1 in the example above, i.e. the value with time 2021-05-31, which is the actual lag value but isn't part of the where clause

Comment: I've changed the coalesce default value to 1, but would this suit other examples?

Comment: Well no, 1 is just here an example, but wihtout searching for it I don't know the value in that row. Apart from that, you could simply recude your statement to include the 1 where null stands and remove the coalesce

Comment: @rst I've just amended my answer. Please check it out and let me know if it meets your needs.

Comment: No it doesn't. I updated the fiddle, maybe my example was not clear enough. Now the content are random values

Comment: I cannot see the fiddle updated. Could you please check?

Comment: I can now see that you've put random numbers. What would you expect instead of a null value?